# Pass data between isolate scope and parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that is supposed to have isolate scope, and a parent directive, something like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
|        parent directive                     |
|  ----------------------------------------   |
|  |                                      |   |
|  |    menu directive(isolate scope)     |   |
|  |                                      |   |
|  ----------------------------------------   |
|                                             |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I would like to know what is the best way to pass data from menu to the parent directive.For example, If the user clicks on the menu item, I would like to pass that item(as well as other data) to the parent directive so that it have a chance to process the action.

I think that this kind of processing shouldn't be coupled to the menu directive, as it main purposes is to show the items and be reusable in other contexts. So, what would be the best practice for passing data from the isolate scope ?

Comment: put some code u have tried ?

Comment: well I have a way that works, and that is basically passing data to the isolate scope { item '=' } and then changing it inside the directive, but I don't like it.

Comment: ok u need to call a functoin on parent directive when something change in `menu` ?

Comment: yes that is pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

- Add a function attribute ("&") to the directive and execute it from the inner directive code. The parent directive code can fetch data from the function's event parameter.
- Emit an event from the inner directive and listen to it in the parent directive.
- Go through $rootScope (usually not recommended)

"Best way" really depends on your specific use case and where you prefer to put the coupling.

Comment: You sure I can emit event from isolate scope?

Answer (score 0):

use "=" instead of "&" while passing the data from parent to child scope you will be getting the change in scope from parent to child and child to parent.